# Что делать если numexpr не работет с большой степенью?

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, numpy, исключения

Когда я пишу большое число и возвожу тоже в большую стерпеть мне ничего не выводится а когда я закрываю скрипт с помою `ctrl+c` то мне выдаёт ошибку `KeyboardInterrupt`. `except` ловит исключение но оно срабатывает только после `ctrl+c`, при повторном нажатии всё закрывается

```
import numexpr

math = input("> ")
count_math = numexpr.evaluate(math)
print(count_math)
```

Comment: Что вы вводите?

Comment: 999999**999999, это минимум

Comment: Наберитесь терпения. Моему компьютеру требуется 5 секунд на само вычисление и около 400 секунд чтобы преобразовать его в десятичное значение длиной 5999994 цифр.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Времена вычисления и печати выражения `999999**999999` в Питоне. Меньше пяти секунд чтобы вычислить степень:

```
$ time python -c 'print((999999**999999).bit_length())'
19931548

real    0m4.435s
user    0m4.420s
sys 0m0.012s
```

Около восьми минут чтобы вычислить и напечатать:

```
$ time python -c 'print(len(str(999999**999999)))'
5999994

real    7m56.762s
user    7m56.664s
sys 0m0.048s
```

В Питоне неэффективная печать больших целых чисел к сожалению. Исправить можно поставив `gmpy`:

```
import gmpy


n = gmpy.mpz(999999)
m = n ** n
print(len(str(m)))
```

Пара секунд на вычисления и печать:

> ```
> $ time python gmpy_sample.py
> 5999994
>
> real  0m1.232s
> user  0m1.216s
> sys   0m0.020s
> ```

Comment: Как установить gmpy? Оно требует Microsoft Visual C++. Можно обойти установку C?

Comment: @Nurlashka давайте угадаем вместе? установить сначала Microsoft Visual C++?

Comment: Без Visual C++ будет трудно. Надо искать подходящий whl файл.

Comment: Кроме gmpy можно поискать gmpy2.

Comment: Мне обязательно нужно использовать нумекспр т.к. я делаю калькулятор в боте и он очень при очень долго считает

Comment: Считайте в `numexpr`, печатайте в `gmpy(2)`. Питон сам считает достаточно быстро, медленно происходить печать гигантских чисел (в которых миллионы цифр).

Comment: Сама идея бота, которые в ответ на выражение вываливает шесть мегабайт текста кажется немного странной. Кто будет их читать?

Comment: Для исключения)

Comment: Как можно просто находить большое вычисление?

Comment: У целого в Питоне есть метод `bit_length()`. Или всегда печатайте через `gmpy.mpz`. На больших числах будет польза, на маленьких никакого вреда не будет.

Comment: Я не могу брать одно число. У меня допустим только: 1+1*999**999

Comment: Всё вычисляете как раньше. Перед печатью переводите результат - обычное целое в `mpz`.